# Class number larger than Minkowski bound

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field.  It is known that the class group is generated by prime ideals with norm less than the Minkowski bound,
$$
B_K:=\frac{n!}{n^n}\left(\frac{4}{\pi} \right)^s \sqrt{|d_K|},
$$
where $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, $s$ is the number of pairs of complex conjugate embeddings of $K$ and $d_K$ is the discriminant.  Let $h_K$ be the class number.  In lots of small examples $h_K \leq B_K$, but upper bounds for $h_K$ in the literature (often given for fixed $n$ in terms of $|d_K|$) are often larger than $B_K$.

Can someone point to an example of a number field with $h_K > B_K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}2]$ has class number $4$ and Minkowski bound
$\frac{2!}{2^2}(4/\pi)^1 \sqrt{39}\approx 3.97$.

Comment: Thanks.  Now finding many imaginary quadratic examples on lmfdb.